# Can the '[[' search algorithm be changed to match a '{' not in column 1?

Tags: search, navigation

I use *terrible* languages that do not even allow you to put the `{` character in the first column. Doing so makes the compiler fail.

When I work on my project in C++, I use the <kbd>[[</kbd> command all the time to go see the top of the function (most often to see a parameter name/type). It would be fantastic if it were possible to have similar functionality in other situations.

I know that I can do <kbd>]]%</kbd> but

1. it's harder to think of it, and
2. I can't use <kbd>''</kbd> to come back to where I was (so I have to use <kbd>ma]]%</kbd> and then <kbd>'a</kbd> to come back... that's even harder to remember to do all of that!)

And if I inadvertently use the <kbd>[[</kbd> I end up on line 1 of the file (In that case, though, I can use <kbd>''</kbd> to come back).

In my case, the language is Go so finding the line is pretty easy, the line starts with `func`  and ends with `{`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `[[` is governed by `:help 'section'`.

In theory, you should be able to give the option a value that suits your needs. In practice, people simply map `[[` and friends to something that works for them. Hell, a number of built-in filetype plugins do that and the help section mentioned above even has the following example:

```
If your '{' or '}' are not in the first column, and you would like to use "[["
and "]]" anyway, try these mappings:
   :map [[ ?{<CR>w99[{
   :map ][ /}<CR>b99]}
   :map ]] j0[[%/{<CR>
   :map [] k$][%?}<CR>
```

Comment: Great! I tried with `:map [[ mZ][%'Z''`. It's similar and works well enough for me.